# CSS Floating Bug in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-float

I'm experiencing a weird issue in the latest version of Chrome (25.0.1364.97 m). I have a set of divs inside a floated, cleared container, all floated left with the same width.

In Firefox, IE, and older versions of Chrome all the boxes sit side by side as they are supposed to but in the latest version of Chrome the first div is above the others like so:

[image]

It only seems to happen when the window is maximised and on the first load, if I refresh the page it sorts itself out, but if i do a hard refresh with Ctrl + F5 it happens again

The HTML:

```
<div id="top">
    <h1>Words</h1>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="box">Words</div>
    <div class="box">Words</div>
    <div class="box">Words</div>
    <div class="box">Words</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {clear:both;float:left;margin-top:20px;width:500px}
.box {float:left;width:100px;border:1px solid #000;margin-right:20px}
```

I've made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/GZHWR/3/

Is this a bug in the latest Chrome?

EDIT: I know this can be solved by applying padding to the #wrapper element instead of margin-top but we manage around 140 sites so it's not practical to go and change the CSS on every one

EDIT 2: I think I need to clarify my question. **I am not asking how to fix the issue**. I already know that. I want to know why this behaviour is occuring? Why is the rendering engine rendering the markup/css like this? Is it correct behaviour?

Comment: works for me on the fiddle

Comment: Looks perfect on Chrome 25.0.1364.97.

Comment: Have Chrome 25.0.1364.97 and everything looks fine

Comment: Is the window maximised? Try a Ctrl + F5 on it?

Comment: I am getting the same result as the OP (26.0.1410.12 beta-m). Removing the `clear` on the container seems to solve the problem.

Comment: When you change the size of the window in jsfiddle the bug appears.

Comment: It also affects stable Chrome releases. I can see the bug after resizing the window. Interesting! +1

Comment: works fine on "chrome 25.0.1364.152 m"

Comment: Do you have any css affecting H1 tags. The tag inside the firsrt .box div may have a width.

Comment: This bug has been reported to Google Chrome forum: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chrome/94s52C4mmgo

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems to be a bug. The problem appears when applying `clear` on the wrapper element. When you remove the `clear`, the bug goes away.

According to the [W3C specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-clear) regarding the `clear` property:

> This property indicates which sides of an element's box(es) may not be
>   adjacent to an earlier floating box. The 'clear' property **does not
>   consider floats inside the element itself** or in other block formatting
>   contexts.

So it shouldn't effect the children's floating behaviour. I filed a bug report at Chrome about this issue.

Update: From the link in the comments, *kjtocool* mentioned on 30-03-2013:

> It appears that this issue has been corrected in version 26.0.1410.43

Comment: Yes it is a new bug in Google Chrome.  See https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chrome/94s52C4mmgo and http://journalxtra.com/websiteadvice/google-chrome-css-rendering-bug-in-version-25-0-1364-97-5355/

Comment: It looks like this bug has re-appeared again in version 59.0.3071.115

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you use

```
display: inline-block;
```

instead of `float: left` for .box?

Comment: Because we manage around 140 sites and I expect the majority have at least one part of the site like this. Not going to edit every site because of a bug in the software

Comment: the problem is not how to avoid the bug, the problem is the bug itself hehe. Anyways, it is a temp solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try :

```
#wrapper {
  display:inline;
}
.box{
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

I had the same issue with the "Like" toolbar and after this code, it work.

Answer (score 0):

remove `clear:both` from `#wrapper`  yes it works..........

http://jsfiddle.net/GZHWR/20/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

css:

```
   .clearfix {
      *zoom: 1;
    }

    .clearfix:before,
    .clearfix:after {
      display: table;
      line-height: 0;
      content: "";
    }

    .clearfix:after {
      clear: both;
    }
```

html:

```
<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
    <div class="box">Words</div>
    <div class="box">Words</div>
    <div class="box">Words</div>
    <div class="box">Words</div>
</div>
```

Remove

```
clear:both;
```

from #wrapper

Answer (score 0):

Remove clear:both from #wrapper and if you still face a problem apply clear:both after last div

Answer (score 0):

Remove clear:both;float:left; form #wrapper

clear:both is require when you want div nex raw.

Comment: I'm beginning to sound like a broken record now. Please read the second edit of the question